# >Find the Equation of ellipse that is tangent to the lines $x-4y=10$ and $x+y=5$

Tags: calculus, conic-sections

> Find the Equation of Ellipse that is tangent to the lines
>   $x-4y=10 $    and  $x+y=5$

I don't know what is the idea of this problem , how can i begin

Thank you for your help

Comment: There are infinitly many of ellipses. We need more informations.

Comment: @scarface  ok , i write  this problem  as written in the book,  but what is idea of this problem , how can i find one ellipse satisfying the conditions of the question?

Comment: Does your ellipse have to be axis-aligned, or could it be arbitrarily oriented?

Comment: I think it could  be arbitrary oriented

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are infinitly many of ellipses. One of them: $ (x+y)^2+(x-4y-5)^2=25 $.

**Solution Method:**
Let's apply affine transformation $u=x+y$, $v=x-4y$. Therefore lines $x+y=5,x-4y=10$ maps to $u=5,v=10$. In the plane $uv$, we need a circle that tangent to lines $u=5,v=10$. For example $u^2+(v-5)^2=25$. Now, in the $xy$ plane, inverse of the circle is an ellipse and

$$ (x+y)^2+(x-4y-5)^2=25 $$

that tangent to $x+y=5,x-4y=10$.

NOTE: We can check [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(x%2By)%5E2%2B(x-4y-5)%5E2%3D25,%20x%2By%3D5,%20x-4y%3D10)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest ellipses are circles. You know that the points on the bisector of an angle are equally far away from the sides of the angle. So in step 1, find a bisecting line. Note that since the original equations describe non-parallel lines, you have 4 angles. Once you found one bisector, take any arbitrary point $(x_0,y_0)$ on it, except the intersection. Find the distance $d$ from that point to one of the lines. That is the radius of the circle. The equation of the ellipse that satisfies your conditions is then $$\frac{(x-x_0)^2}{d^2}+\frac{(y-y_0)^2}{d^2}=1$$